# Elasticsearch spring implementation error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have a interface which has function used to query ElasticSearch. It extends the ElasticsearchRepository for doing it.

```
public interface HouseholdRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<SearchHouseholdESBean, String> {
    List<SearchHouseholdESBean> findByPhoneNumberAndActiveInd(String phoneNumber, String activeInd);
```

The problem is how do i call this in my business class where i need to get the results. This being an interface , i can't create an object of this to call the methods. Also, the implementation is implicit to the jars in the Elastic Search.

Comment: You cannot instantiate an object but you can autowire it.

Comment: @georges van I tried something like :- "@Autowired
    private HouseholdRepository householdRepository;"  in the implementation class but the object is null. What can be the reason for this ?

Answer (score 1):

To use elastichsearch repositories you must follow the next steps:
1. add annotation `@EnableElasticsearchRepositories` on your SpringBootApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories
public class Application {
//...
```

2. Make sure that the interface `HouseholdRepository` is scanned by the spring-boot application. You can simple achieve this by placing it under the same root package as your `Application` class.

3.You will just `@Autowire HouseholdRepository` in your service without further changes. The idea behind spring boot data is that the code will be generated based on that interface.

OBS: make sure that you have the proper project dependencies. You should depend on `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` to avoid extra configuration effort.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have following in the configuration file where i instatiate my transport client "@ EnableElasticsearchRepositories
@ Configuration
@ ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.amdocs.bda.ccr"}) 
public class CCRServicesConfig  { @ Bean
 public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {" Will this suffice or i have to add "@ SpringBootApplication" annotation to the same file as well